# Custom query with 'tax_query' and 'meta_key' returning no results

Tags: wp-query

This is s query that I'm using on my website:

```
$arguments = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key'  =>  '_count-views_all',
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value',        
    'tax_query' =>  array(
        array (
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'term'  => 'student-success-stories',
        ),
    ),
);

$ajaxQuery = new WP_Query( $arguments );
```

Unfortunately, the query does not return any posts although posts with all of the queried fields are present.

Is there a problem with my `$arguments` syntax? My second thought was that maybe`'tax_query'` cannot go with higher level arguments like `'meta_key'`.

If you see any issues with the query, please share your thoughts/

Comment: Your meta key name looks fishy. `_count-views_all`. Are you sure about that. Shouldn't it be `_count_views_all` as the correct synatx for separating names should be underscores

Comment: @Peter, I know that _count-views_all looks wierd, but this is a meta key introduced to the database by one of the plugins I'm using, namely Post Views Count ([https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-post-views-count/]).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these two custom queries?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175054/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-custom-queries)