# What is the difference between these two custom queries?

Tags: wp-query

Could you please explain what the difference is between the following two custom queries?

```
$arguments = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key'  =>  '_count-views_all',
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value',        
    'tax_query' =>  array(
        array (
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'term'  => 'student-success-stories',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and

```
$arguments = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key'  =>  '_count-views_all',
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value',     
    'category_name' => 'student-success-stories',
);
```

The first query does not return any results on my website while the second works as desired. I was convinced that they shoudl be doing the same thing. Apparently this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `terms` (plural) not `term` (singular) in tax query arguments. :)

Comment: OMG! This is definitely THE ANSWER :D